# javascript doesn't work in Windows Server 2008 explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, windows-server-2008

i have a web application that sits on IIS 7 inside a windows serve 2008,
The web application has a button that calls a javascript function:

```
<td align="left">
  <button name="openWin" type="button" onclick="openAccountWin('<%#  GlobalUrl+"mypage.aspx?name="+Eval("biz") %>')">Company page</button>
 </td>

<script type="text/javascript">
function openAccountWin(url) {
    debugger;
    top.location.href = url;
}
```

when i push the button on the explorer, nothing happens.
if i do it in firefox it work!
when i do the same on a same application (same code) that sits in win 7 station with iis 7 too, it works too!.

i enabled javascript debugging,
i lowered to the minimum the explorer trusted sites, and add the page to trusted sites.
it must be an explorer problem...

Comment: *Nothing* very rarely happens, so what happens exactly? Do you get any error message?

Comment: i push the button and nothing happens, the page isn't even refreshed. everything stays the same. in firefox it works (the page is redirected by the othr page).

Comment: Change your internet settings so that Javascript error messages are shown in IE. Otherwise they are only visible as an icon in the status bar.

Comment: @Guffa , thanks but how do i do that ?

Comment: Internet Options > Advanced > enable "Display a notification about every script error". (Exact wording may differ depending on version.)